# The name 'Tensor' refers to a Tensor which does not exist. The operation, 'Tensor', does not exist in the graph

Tags: python, tensorflow, save, load, restore

I know, this question has already been asked but none of the answers worked for me.
I'm trying to restore a model that I saved before. I used both the classical TF saver and the SavedModel. But the problem when loading remains the same. I get the error message as in the header:

> "The name 'train_op:0' refers to a Tensor which does not exist. The operation, 'train_op', does not exist in the graph."

Well I get it that train_op is somehow not in the restored model graph but I don't know why. 
I'm creating the train_op variable and assigning a name to it:  `train_op = optimizer.apply_gradients(grads_and_vars, global_step=global_step, name="train_op")`. I'm saving the model using simple_save:

```
tf.saved_model.simple_save(sess,
            model_file,
            inputs={"x": X, "y": y},
            outputs={"z": loss})
```

This is how I am loading the model:

```
tf.saved_model.loader.load(sess, [tf.saved_model.tag_constants.SERVING], model_file)
```

This is the line of code where the model appears:

```
 _, summary = sess.run(["train_op:0", "summary_op:0"], feed_dict={"X-input:0": X_batch, "y-input:0": y_batch}, run_metadata=run_metadata)
```

I really don't understand the issue. I get the same problem for the other variables so it's not specific to `train_op`.

Thanks!